# Why is a table showing up twice in pg_class?

Tags: postgresql, query

I am attempting to run a PostgreSQL statement to **query approximate table size count estimate** using the following statement:

```
SELECT reltuples as approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

ref: [Count estimate](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate) (PostgreSQL | Wiki)

However, my query is returning two rows, one with a size and one with zero.
Why?

Comment: This is not a typo question, not sure why the close votes...I put it here because googling for this issue yielded no answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had the same table (same name) within two different schemas.  So each had an entry in pg_class.

Work around from the wiki page is `SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'schema_name.table_name'::regclass;`